# How to show that a bound is sharp?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I know that $b$ is a sharp upper bound for $X$ if $b\geq x$ for all $x \in X$ **and** there exists an $b_0 \in X$ such that $b=b_0$.

1. But what if we have two bounds for $X$, i.e if $a\leq x\leq b$ for all $x \in X$, does that mean that I have to find two elements $a_0$ and $b_0$ in $X$ such that $b=b_0$ and $a=a_0$?
2. (an example given in our lecture notes) If I do have two find two values, then why is $f=z^p-c z^{p+1},p\in N$ is an example that shows the inequality $|z|^p-c |z|^{p+1}\leq|f(z)|\leq |z|^p+c |z|^{p+1},\forall f\in W$ is sharp? I mean, shouldn't there be two functions for each bound?

Comment: I question your definition for a sharp upper bound. I’ve always understood sharp bounds to mean the bound cannot be improved in any way. Example: $f(x)=-e^{x}\leq0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. However, $0$ is a sharp upper bound because any lesser bound would actually be untrue for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Clayton, but when we have two bounds $a\leq x\leq b$ do we need to give two examples?

Comment: By definition, you’re looking for a sharp **upper** bound. There is only one sharp upper bound.